# Bundled wires in quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

The following quantikz code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
  \qwbundle[alternate]{} & \ctrlbundle{1} &  \gate{R} \\
  \qw & \targ{} & \qw 
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

results in this circuit diagram:

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

What should I change to have three wires going into the final R gate?

As far as I understood from the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz), the number of wires should be automatically defined by the preceding circuit element.

Comment: Please provide a complete example, also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This helps others to help you.

Comment: Most users on this site, including I myself, are not familiar with quantum circuit. For example, I don't know which part is the final gate. Can you provide a sketch showing what output you want?

Comment: Sorry! Made changes to the post.

Comment: Your code is still not compilable.

Comment: It may not be compilable if you are using Overleaf, but it should work if you use the files from the official [package page](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz). (Those can also be added to the Overleaf root folder of the project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (a `\qwbundle[alternate]{}` is added after `\gate{R}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
  \qwbundle[alternate]{} & \ctrlbundle{1} &  \gate{R}\qwbundle[alternate]{} \\
  \qw & \targ{} & \qw 
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I haven't read through the package documentation, instead I just searched for `\qwbundle` and learnt its usage from the last two examples in sec. III, upper part of page 4.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much.